# CAn't query within a boundary box mongodb,spring data(1.6.1)

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query:

```
{ 
    $in: [ "a9bba0ae-bc84-4582-853a-6dbd34e3d184" ], 
    $within: { $box: [ [ -28.031753, -180.0 ], [ 90.0, 180.0 ] ] } 
};
```

nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query

Java:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("indexKey").in(indexKey).within(shape));
```

im using Spring Data..however i can't find what is wrong with the query?  im not allowed to query on Boundary boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query the statement you use would try to execute a geo search on the `indexKey` which does not seem to hold geo coordinates. Please use the `.and` to explicitly concat the location criteria.

```
 query(
   where("indexKey")
     .in("a9bba0ae-bc84-4582-853a-6dbd34e3d184")
     .and("location")
     .within(new Box(new double[] {-28.031753D, -180.0D}, new double[] {90.0D, 180.0D})));
```